Inverse function theorem generalization
In inverse function theorem, it requires $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Can it be applied to the case that $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n>m$. In other words, how do I determine whether the function $Y=f(X)$ is invertible when the number of functions is greater than the number of independent variables?
Some posts mention the implicit function theorem but it seems that the theorem only works for the case that there are more independent variables than the functions, where $n\leq m$.
The background of this question is: I have a system of equations $Y=F(X)$ where the number of equations is greater than the number of independent variables. And I want to have a metric that determines "given Y, how 'easy' can I obtain X".

If $m \neq n$ $f$ cannot be both invertible and continuous. That would violate invariance of domain.

So if I want to find X given Y, the only thing I can do is to use the least square method?

In the case where $n = m + k$, for $k$ an integer greater than $1$, we have a similar theorem that garantees (with some assumptions) that $f$ behaves locally as inclusion.
This Theorem is
Local Immersion Theorem. Let $f: \Bbb{R}^m \to \Bbb{R}^{m+k}$ a smooth application such that $df_x$ is injective for $x \in \Bbb{R}^m$ (in this case, we say that $f$ is an immersion). Let $y = f(x)$. Thus, there exist open neighborhoods $x \in U\subseteq\Bbb{R}^m$, $0\in V\subseteq\Bbb{R}^{k}$, $y \in W\subseteq \Bbb{R}^{n+k}$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:W \to U\times V$ such that
$$(\phi \circ f)(x) = (x,0).$$
In a general context of smooth manifolds: If $M$ is a $m$-dimensional smooth manifold, $N$ is a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, with $m\leq n$, and $f:M\to N$ a immersion at $p$, ie, $df_p: T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$ is injective  $p \in M$, there exist local coordinates around $p$ and $f(p)$ such that
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_m) = (x_1,\dots,x_n,0,\dots,0).$$
Homework: What happen when $f:\Bbb{R}^{k+m}\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is smooth application where $df_x$ is surjective? What is it's local behavior?

 In this case, $f$ is called a submersion at $x$. Locally it behaves as projection onto $\Bbb{R}^m \hookrightarrow\Bbb{R}^{k+m}$. This is the result of Local Submersion Theorem.


 Local Submersion Theorem: Let $f:\Bbb{R}^{k+m}\to\Bbb{R}^m$ a smooth application and $x \in \Bbb{R}^{k+m}$ such that $df_x$ is surjective. Writting $\Bbb{R}^{k+m} = \Bbb{R}^k \oplus \Bbb{R}^m = \Bbb{R}^k \times \Bbb{R}^m$ and $x = (a,b)$, $df_x$ restricted to $\Bbb{R}^m$ is an isomorphism and there are neighborhoods $x \in U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{k+m}$, $a \in V \subseteq \Bbb{R}^k$, $f(x) \in W\subseteq\Bbb{R}^m$, and a diffeomorphism $\phi: V \times W \to U$ such that $$(f \circ \phi)(x,w) = w, \quad \forall (x,w) \in V \times W.$$

Recommended reading:

Guillemin, Pollack - Differential Topology
Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds


Thank you for the detailed answer! As a person not from a math background, it is a little bit hard for me to understand the theorem. Could you give an example of the Local Immersion Theorem? The background of this question is: I have a system of equations Y=F(X) where the number of equations is greater than the number of independent variables. And I want to have a metric that determines "given Y, how 'easy' can I obtain X".

What you are asking is related to non linear system of equations, I am right?

Yes! I now believe it's an over-determined nonlinear system problem.
